# Align many short sequences from two lists and find complementary

Tags: r, string, dna-sequence

So I have two list objects in R and I want to know which of the sequences can bind to each other through DNA complementarity.

The first object rs is reverse complement microRNA seed regions and the second is 3'UTRs motifs.
Any lead on how to solve this problem? 
I found a package called microRNAs (https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/microRNA/man/microRNA.pdf) with a function called matchSeeds(seed, seq). I did this but this function is actually looking for exact matches, which is not exactly what I need. Any lead on how to solve this in R will be very much appreciated.
Thanks!

```
> typeof(rs)
[1] "list"
> typeof(u)
[1] "list"

head(rs)
$`miR-92|34108_3p `
[1] "TGCAAT"

$`miR-92|34106_3p `
[1] "TGCAAT"

$`miR-92|34110_3p `
[1] "TGCAAT"

$`miR-184|1952_3p `
[1] "CCGTCC"

$`miR-184|1954_3p `
[1] "CCGTCC"

$`miR-1795_3p `
[1] "CCGTCC"

head(u)
$upper_1
[1] "gccgtt"

$upper_2
[1] "ccgagc"

$upper_3
[1] "gacatt"

$upper_4
[1] "gcttat"

$upper_5
[1] "taccta"

$upper_6
[1] "tcgtct"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find if any substrings in `rs` list are complementary to the strings in `u` list, and you want it to be performant you can use package Biostrings function `matchPDict`.

Example:

```
library(Biostrings)
library(IRanges)

lis <- list(`miR-92|34108_3p ` = "TGCAAT",
            `miR-92|34106_3p ` = "TGCAAT",
            `miR-92|34110_3p ` = "TGCAAT")

u <- list(upper_1 ="gccgtt",
          upper_2 = "ccgagc",
          upper_3 = "gacatt",
          upper_4 = "gcttat",
          upper_5 = "taccta")
```

Convert first list to DNAStringSet:

```
lis <- DNAStringSetList(lis)
lis <- unlist(lis)
```

Convert second list to DNAStringSet:

```
u <- DNAStringSetList(u)
u <- unlist(u)
```

Get the complement of lis

```
lis_rc <- complement(lis)
```

create a PDict so you can match it fast vs the other list

```
pdict0 <- PDict(lis_rc)
```

iterate over list `u` running `matchPDict`

```
lapply(u, function(x) matchPDict(pdict0, x))
```

EDIT: if you want to check any orientation you can create them using accesory functions such as `complement`, `reverse` and `reverseComplement`  and provide that to `PDict`:

```
lis_rc <- c(lis,
            complement(lis),
            reverse(lis),
            reverseComplement(lis))

names(lis_rc) <- paste(trimws(names(lis_rc)), rep(c("",
                                            "c",
                                            "r",
                                            "rc"),
                                          each = length(lis)),
                                            sep = "_")

pdict0 <- PDict(lis_rc)

res <- lapply(u, function(x) matchPDict(pdict0, x))
```

`res` is a list of IRanges objects

you can check where the hits are with

```
lapply(res, width)
lapply(res, start)
lapply(res, end)
```

EDIT2:

if you just want to count the matches without the match coordinates you can simply use:

```
vcountPDict(pdict0, u)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0
[11,]    0    0    0    0    0
[12,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

rows correspond to sequences in `pdict0`, while columns correspond to sequences in `u`:

```
mat <- vcountPDict(pdict0, u)
rownames(mat) <- names(lis_rc)
colnames(mat) <- names(u)

                   upper_1 upper_2 upper_3 upper_4 upper_5
miR-92|34108_3p_         0       0       0       0       0
miR-92|34106_3p_         0       0       0       0       0
miR-92|34110_3p_         0       0       0       0       0
miR-92|34108_3p_c        0       0       0       0       0
miR-92|34106_3p_c        0       0       0       0       0
miR-92|34110_3p_c        0       0       0       0       0
miR-92|34108_3p_r        0       0       0       0       0
miR-92|34106_3p_r        0       0       0       0       0
miR-92|34110_3p_r        0       0       0       0       0
miR-92|34108_3p_rc       0       0       0       0       0
miR-92|34106_3p_rc       0       0       0       0       0
miR-92|34110_3p_rc       0       0       0       0       0
```

Comment: check out also `countPDict`, `whichPDict` which might be more appropriate for your use case. Especially easy to use might be the vectorized  `vcountPDict`: using the object in the answer `vcountPDict(pdict0, u)`